# Problem with combobox, it didn't load de options (pyqt5)

Tags: events, combobox, pyqt5, qt5

I have a program that when I press a pushbutton it loads the options of my combombox, I have three, but for a unknown reason only two works. This function read a .txt file, and then put the strings in the combobox. I tried with addItem() and addItems(), made function again and it didn't work. The function read another two combobox and then loads the options.This is the function:

```
def cargar_combobox_flujos2(self,event):    
    anho = int(self.ui.combobox_anho.itemText(self.ui.combobox_anho.currentIndex()))
    mes_input = self.ui.combobox_mes.itemText(self.ui.combobox_mes.currentIndex())
    dic = {'Enero': 1, 'Febrero': 2, 'Marzo': 3, 'Abril': 4, 'Junio': 5, 'Julio': 7, 'Agosto': 8, 'Septiembre': 9,
           'Octubre': 10, 'Noviembre': 11, 'Diciembre': 12}
    mes = int(dic.get(mes_input))
    lista_ssee=[]
    nombre_txt='Graficos Flujos/lista_cbbx_'+str(anho)+'_'+str(mes)+'.txt'
    if os.path.isfile(nombre_txt)==True:
        archivo = open(nombre_txt, 'r')
        c=archivo.read()
        lista=c.split(',')
        for i in lista:
            lista_ssee.append(i)
        archivo.close()
   option_barras= self.ui.comboBox_barras_CMg2.count()
   if option_barras > 1:
        self.ui.comboBox_barras_CMg2.clear()
   for barra in lista_ssee:
        self.ui.comboBox_barras_CMg2.addItems(barra)
```

Comment: Are you sure that the file is actually opened and `lista_ssee` gets correctly populated? Add an `else` after the `if os.path.isfile` to warn you about the failed reading, and a `print(lista_ssee)` at the end of that function to see its contents.

Comment: yes, in my real code I have the option else to calculate lista_see with a imported function, and also I tried with print() but it didn't works :(. In the program it appears only the first value of the list, but I can't oppened  the combobox

Comment: "and also I tried with print() but it didn't work" do you mean that it prints an empty list? If that's the case, it means that the problem is in the part of the code that is responsible of populating the list, so it's either a file reading issue or the imported function you told us about; in both cases, we cannot help you, unless you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), as your current code is insufficient to understand the cause of the issue.

Comment: sorry my  english is not very good, "and also I tried with print() but it didn't work" it means that when I print de list, the list have no problem but the problem didn't solve, thanks for you answer

Comment: Then you have to provide a MRE anyway, as that excerpt of code is not enough right now.

Comment: That's why providing a MRE is almost always a good idea :-) I suggest you to delete this post, as questions about issues caused by typos or that are not reproducible are normally closed anyway.

Comment: The problem was that I have another element (type QLabel) that was up to the combobox, for that reason the combobox didn't open. I resize the elements and then it works

Comment: From what you're describing, you're probably setting fixed geometries (position and size) of widgets, which is generally highly discouraged for lots of reasons (including what you are experiencing), and there are very few specific cases for which that is actually required. You should prefer to use [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) instead (they can be [created in Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html) too).

Comment: Yes,it's difficult, its the first time that I made a frame, but its very usefull for my work, also I learned by myself, so I didn't know that xD